# Rubymine doesn't regonize shared context variables

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubymine

I have specs that use variables from a shared context. The set up looks something like this:

shared_context.rb

```
RSpec.shared_context :handy_things do    
    let(:handy_object)  { ... }
end
```

test_spec.rb:

```
require 'shared_context.rb'
describe 'Something happens' do
  include_context :handy_things

  before(:each) do
    handy_object.option = true
  end
...
```

The `handy_object` from the context is not recognized by Rubymine. I get an inspection message 'Cannot find...'.
This is not the end of the world but it annoys me.

Is there a way to let Rubymine know the variables of the shared context are accessible everywhere. Or as workaround to add my shared_context variables to some kind of dictionary so Rubymine doesn't flag it as unknown?

Comment: If someone answers your question, then fine, otherwise raise a bug to JetBrains.

Comment: This is the corresponding bug report: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-23205. Add your vote if you want this.

Answer (score -1):

You might try two things:

Replacing your `require` with `require_relative "shared_context"` (with the relative path included if they're in different folders, no .rb extension necessary)

Specifying `require "./shared_context"`

Comment: Sadly enough, it didn't make any difference.